# Ubuntu installation failure 16.04

Tags: system-installation, usb, 16.04, usb-creator

I am trying to install ubuntu 16.04 alongside windows 10.

The checksum is correct, however after creating a bootable usb with the iso, the usb finds 2 errors when verifying before installation.

I have used 2 different tools to create the usb (rufus, UUI).

I have redownloaded the iso and tried recreating the usb.

I have used a different usb stick.

All of these had 2 errors, and all of them, when trying out ubuntu, the ubuntu system loaded, but had a flashing error message that slowly decended the screen, and nothing else. nothing was clickable.

Any ideas on where I have gone wrong?

I am very confused by this whole process.

Comment: What were the two errors, exactly? What did the flashing error message say?`

Comment: I ran the verify disk option that appears when booting to the usb, it said it found two errors in the installation media, but not what they were specifically, is there a way to check?

Comment: I don't know. I would re-download the ISO file if I were you.

Comment: I did that, two errors again. Is it possible that the issues with installation are not caused by these errors? This http://askubuntu.com/questions/381843/live-usb-check-disk-for-defects-returns-defects seems to suggest the errors are expected.

Comment: I really don't know... hopefully someone else can help. I am curious what the error message was when you booted ubuntu normally (not using the "verify disk" option, but just a normal "try ubuntu" boot).

Comment: Managed to get a photo in between the flashes https://imgur.com/8IUNtgE